# Remove comma as thousands separator from quoted numbers in a CSV using sed

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed

My `sed` is pretty shaky, so I'm not sure how to take a row like this

```
1,2,"12,345",x,y,"a,b"
```

and turn it into

```
1,2,12345,x,y,"a,b"
```

So the number "12,345" becomes 12345, but "a,b" remains untouched.

I would need to somehow preserve the values around the comma when the values are numeric. I have an idea how the regex would look like to only deal with digits, but not really sure how to just remove the comma, as opposed to removing the whole column.

Comment: Trying to manipulate data that's in a specific form is asking for trouble.  Parse the data, clean it up, and write it back out.  See either of the Perl solutions below.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing CSV should be done with a proper csv parser. I would recommend `perl` as well.

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -ne '
    @line = parse_line(",", 1, $_); 
    print join "," , map { s/,//g if $_ =~ /^[0-9,"]+$/; $_ } @line
' text.csv
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat text.csv
1,2,"12,345",x,y,"a,b"
"a,c","12,345",x,y,"a,b"
```

```
$ perl -MText::ParseWords -ne '
    @line = parse_line(",", 1, $_);
    print join "," , map { s/,//g if $_ =~ /^[0-9,"]+$/; $_ } @line
' text.csv
1,2,"12345",x,y,"a,b"
"a,c","12345",x,y,"a,b"
```

To make in-place changes you can use `-i` option or re-direct the output to another file.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution, using [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my @rows;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary => 1}) or die 'Text::CVS'->error_diag;
open my $IN, '<', 'file.csv' or die $!;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($IN)) {
    for my $cell (@$row) {
        $cell =~ s/,// if $cell =~ /^[0-9,]+$/;
    }
    push @rows, $row;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag;

open my $OUT, '>', 'new.csv' or die $!;
$csv->print($OUT, $_) for @rows;
close $OUT or die $!;
```

Answer (score 1):

In one regex substitution you could do something as nasty as this:
`/\G(?|(")(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*(")|()([^,]+)()())(,|$)/g`
replace with
`\1\2\3\4\5`

This should work fine with Perl.

demo: http://regex101.com/r/kQ5fU1

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo '1,2,"12,345",x,y,"a,b"' | sed 's/"\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\)"/\1\2/g'
```

EDIT: Actually, my solution only works if there is one comma enclosed between double quotes.

Comment: There will be at most two commas, so would that be sed 's/"\([0-9]+\),\([0-9]+\)\(,\([0-9]+\)){0-1}"/\1\2\3/g' ?

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `(\d),(\d)(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` and replace w/ `$1$2`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pG8uM4)